# How do I get my crontab environment set correctly to run my ant build.xml file?

Tags: java, ant, selenium-webdriver, testng, cron

How do I get my crontab environment set correctly to run my ant build.xml file?

I’d like to schedule some selenium web driver tests to run overnight using crontab.  My tests are run in java and use TestNG.  Tests run great from Eclipse and using ant, I can run them from the command line, but when I try to schedule them using crontab, I run into issues.  After doing some research, it seems this is a pretty common problem related to crontab’s environment.   I’ve tried writing a wrapper that crontab runs before my ant command and I’ve tried setting the variables directly in crontab, but nothing seems to work.

Actually, my ‘clean’ and ‘compile’ targets from my build.xml file work great.  It is just the ‘run’ target that always fails.

What am I doing wrong?  Is this a crontab issue or a TestNG issue?  I should also add that my browser never starts when using crontab, so it seems like a crontab environmental issue.

My crontab file (setting my env variables directly):

```
PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin::/Users/<user>/Downloads/EXIFutilsOSX3.1:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=326
TERM_SESSION_ID=52A896A6-2447-4114-A45A-72000A9D6827
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
SECURITYSESSIONID=186a4
DISPLAY=:0
19 * * * * /Users/<user>/Downloads/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin/ant -buildfile /Users/<user>/local_repo/qa-automation/selenium-java/My-projects/build.xml run
```

And here is my crontab output:

```
run:
    [testng] [TestNG] Running:
    [testng]   /Users/<username>/local_repo/qa-automation/selenium-java/My-projects/my-project1.xml
    [testng] 
    [testng] ===============================================
    [testng] my-project1
    [testng] Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
    [testng] Configuration Failures: 2, Skips: 2
    [testng] ===============================================
    [testng] The tests failed.
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have test report files?  What do they contain?

Comment: X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin::/Users/me/Downloads/EXIFutilsOSX3.1:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal>
X-Cron-Env: <TERM=xterm-256color>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/bash>
X-Cron-Env: <TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=326>
X-Cron-Env: <TERM_SESSION_ID=52A896A6-2447-4114-A45A-72000A9D6827>
X-Cron-Env: <LANG=en_US.UTF-8>
X-Cron-Env: <SHLVL=1>
X-Cron-Env: <SECURITYSESSIONID=186a4>
X-Cron-Env: <DISPLAY=:0>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=me>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=me>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/me>

Comment: I meant test result files created by TestNG.

Comment: No.  None of the TestNG report files normally in the test-output folder are getting created when the 'run' target is called using crontab.  The class files are being created though (in the build folder).

Comment: Interestingly, crontab has no issue with the following line.
    18 * * * * /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox 

Firefox is started no problem.  Another clue.  Hopefully I'll have my answer soon.